# Contract expiring, expected to train new hire alongside regular work

Tags: training, new-hires

So basically I am an IT contractor working on some new cutting edge technologies. My contract is about to expire in 3 months and it looks like it won't be extended due to budgeting reasons.

They have hired a fresh masters student and are now asking me to train him on new technology. The new technology is highly advanced, and I doubt that student has any programming skills. Also, I will have to train them along with doing my work.

How do I handle this situation?

Comment: Do as your asked and start looking for other work. Make sure your employer knows that you would like to continue working for them. Send honest reports about progress of the hire. I'm not sure what the situation you want help with is? Dealing with needing a new job? Dealing with an inexperienced hire? The realization that your contract won't be renewed?

Comment: Dealing with the inexperienced hire as they expect him to take over my job responsibility which won't happen as he just isn't experienced enough. They are expecting me to make him pro in the coming three months which doesn't sound realistic.

Comment: But you're gone in 3 months anyway.  What are they going to do to you at that point?

Comment: Do your best to train him in the time you have left, since that's what you are being paid to do. Whether he succeeds or fails after that is not your problem; delivering honest value is.

Comment: Broad questions like "How do I handle this situation?" are problematic here. Could you explain where you see a problem, and what your goal is?

Comment: Exactly @sleske, you should first tell us what you want.

Comment: "I doubt that student has any programming skills" - what is the basis for this statement? Did you interview the new hire?

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I would suggest training as much as possible, leave sufficient documentation then drift off into the sunset in 3 months.

If you can leave a working, well documented system, then your job is done.

Answer (score 1):

What are you struggling with? You've been asked to do a job, you do it. You're entitled to raise your concerns with management:

> Hi boss. I've seen the new employee's CV and I'm worried he doesn't have the technical background to be able to run this system.

and you're entitled to ask how much of your time you should spend training the new employee rather than doing your regular work, but if you've be told to train the new guy, you train the new guy to the best of your ability.